# Animate objects when UIScrollView scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, quartz-core

I have a `UIScrollView` which has two pages and only scroll horizontally.

The scrolling and paging is controlled using a `UIPageControl`. I have placed a `UIImageView` on the scrollView which contains an image of an iPhone (shown in red in the image below) that says *Hello* inside page 1.

I wanted to animate the `UIImageView` to rotate and change its position as shown in the image when the user scrolls from page-1 to page-2. Also the animation should ideally rotate back when the user is scrolling back from page-2 to page-1.

[image: Animation based on UIScrollView]

The animation or movement of the `UIImageView` is based on how much the user is scrolling horizontally and not based on time.

How can I rotate the `UIImageView` back and forth based on the scroll position of the `UIScrollView`?

Comment: you can use `CABasicAnimation` with `transform.rotation` animationWithKeyPath for doing this type of rotation animation with @rob's suggestion

Comment: animationWithKeyPath you mention. You might know where to find more information beside Apple Doc's

Comment: check this:- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a delegate for your scroll view.  Probably you want your view controller to be the delegate.  You need to add `UIScrollViewDelegate` to its list of protocols.

Then, in the delegate, implement `scrollViewDidScroll:`.  In `scrollViewDidScroll:`, look at the scroll view's `contentOffset`.  Based on the `contentOffset`, set the image view's `transform` and `center` to rotate and move it where you want.

Comment: could you add an example of using `transform` with `contentOffset`

Answer (score 1):

To find by how much the scroll view has scrolled, you can check UIScrollView's contentOffset property:

> contentOffset - The point at which the origin of the content view is
>   offset from the origin of the scroll view.

Then to rotate that image view, you could do this:

```
self.imageview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

As far as the animation goes, I personally don't have much experience with it. But you could have a look at [Simple Animation Using UIImageView](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/).

Comment: instead of fixed M_PI/2 , we may need to vary angle as per the content offset